# Mockito - InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: java, service, mocking, mockito

I have been trying to debug this piece of code for a while now but still no luck. I continues to throw "InvalidUseOfMatchersException" specifically for this code:

For the set up:

```
        service = mock(Service.class);
        newRequest = mock(Request.class);
        when(service.newRequest(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(
            newRequest);
```

And in the class that service is used in:

```
 Request newRequest = Service.newRequest(
            mId, "mp", itemID);
```

I am assuming that it fails because I pass in 3 "anyString()" in the when...thenReturn clause but it could possibly be that it is failing on the hardcoded "mp". So I tried to replace the when clause with this:

```
when(service.newRequest(anyString(), eq("mp"), anyString())).thenReturn(
            newRequest);
```

But still receive the InvalidUseOfMatchersException.

Am I missing something about how mockito is supposed to work for this?

full stack:

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 2 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
    at ServiceFacade.getSimilarities(ServiceFacade.java:29)
    at FacadeTest.getSimilarities(FacadeTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stack trace and message.

Comment: The **same** exception happens for your 1st and 3rd snippet?

Comment: yes both return the same exception @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: With the same expected/recorded counts?

Comment: yes with the 3 matchers expected, 2 recorded @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this syntax:

```
Service.newRequest(mId, "mp", itemID);
```

It looks like `newRequest` is a static method. Mockito inherently works by subclassing (actually generating dynamic proxies), so it doesn't work on static methods because the static method can't be overridden through subclassing. Final methods aren't mockable for similar reasons.

If that's correct, switch to a factory object instead of factory method, which will let you mock the instance of the factory, or use [Powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#Mocking_Static_Method) to mock static fields.